# Do I have to use my real name to set up a Gmail account

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-account

When signing up for a new Gmail account, it asks for your first and last name. Do I have to put in my real name?

I have a few other accounts, along with a YouTube account, and every time I login to any of them, my name follows. I don't like using my real name. I also tried to create a new channel with a new Gmail account, and every time I try to upload a video, the screen fades out. Or if I click the *create a channel* link, it fades out. What is causing this? No one in the YouTube forum can answer this question, and I didn't find anyone that is having this problem. Would you happen to know what’s going on?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is split into two parts, and so shall my answer. :D

Firstly, you don't necessarily need to put your real name (although it is a requirement by Google). You can just put your nickname and make it look convincing that it is a name, and you should be okay with it.

If you don't need Gmail, you can just [follow the steps here](http://lifehacker.com/5877927/how-to-sign-up-for-a-google-account-without-being-forced-into-google%252B-or-gmail) and you should be alright.

Also, you don't necessarily have to link your Youtube account with your original Google account. While it is the default for new accounts created, you can simply disconnect it in your account settings, as stated in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39670/youtube-shows-real-name-when-i-post).

Secondly, did you check if you disabled Javascript when browsing Youtube? I am not exactly sure what the problem is that results in your "screen fading away", but do check for the common browser issues regarding the browsing of the site. If you still can't fix it, I would suggest [contacting Youtube directly](http://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us) to ask your question so that it can receive more professional help.

Comment: The only way Google got my full name is, apparently, because I linked my Android tablet and entered a credit card to make purchases in the Play store.  If I change to the wrong name, will this affect the ability to make such purchases?