# YouTube shows real name when I post

Tags: youtube, google-account

I forget when it happened but somehow YouTube linked with my Gmail account, which sucks because now when I post on a YouTube video everyone sees my real name. How can I change this?

This question is in need of updated answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your display name by doing the following:

1. Log in to your desired account on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com).
2. Click on the down arrow on the top right hand corner next to your profile picture (if you have one).
3. Select "YouTube settings". Click on "Advanced" under "Account Information".
4. Click "Disconnect with Google+" account. Note that with this, you are creating a channel for yourself with a separate username.
5. After completing the steps, you will have your own username. This username will become your display name afterwards.

Note however, that you cannot actually set a proper display name with spaces if you use this method, but it does separate your real name from your YouTube account.

---

Alternatively, you can just go to your Google Account and change your real name to something else (though it is going to change it on every single Google product you use, especially your Gmail). You can follow these steps:

1. In YouTube, click on the down arrow on the top right hand corner next to your profile picture.
2. Under "Google account", click on "Profile".
3. Assuming you have your Google+ account created, click on your name in the profile page and change it to your desired name accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I'm also interested, could you please elaborate on how to change my name on my Google Account?

Comment: Edited to show the alternative method. Hope this helps! :D

Comment: I don't think these instructions work anymore. I don't see the disconnect with google+ option.

Comment: Related meta post: [Question asked but answer no longer valid](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/question-asked-but-answer-no-longer-valid)

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a secondary channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861?hl=en) without your real name:

- Go to [All my channels](http://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher).
- Click `Create a new channel`.

The next time you log in to Youtube, it will ask you what channel you want to use. You may select the `Don't ask me again` box to always browse Youtube using your new channel automatically.

You may also want to [import existing playlists from a channel to your new channel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70934/14334).